# RedirectView with dynamic parameter in url

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch-admin

So, in my controller I have a method with mapping `@RequestMapping(value = "/profile-{id}/launch")` and at the end of it I want to redirect the flow to other method within same controller with mapping `@RequestMapping(value = "/profile-{id}/executions")` ...
I am obligated to inject `RedirectView` bean with xml configuration. So I have something like

```
<bean name="redirect:executions" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView">
        <property name="url" value="#{resourceService.servletPath}/profile-{id}/executions" />
        <property name="contextRelative" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

but how am I going to target specific profile ID, since at the end of first method I have to write return "redirect:executions" cause I am targeting the name of the bean, and it cant be dynamic.

Or I target the url with something like `return "redirect:/profile-"+someID+"/executions"`

Comment: If it is in the same controller, why don't you just make a private method that accepts the id as a parameter, then call the private method.  There shouldn't even be a need to mess with the redirect:executions bean.

Comment: You mean to call method that has `@RequestMapping(value = "/profile-{id}/executions")` directly .... like `getExecutions(1);` ... not with redirecting the view? @Shaggy125

Comment: Yes.  If the method is `@RequestMapping(value = "/profile-{id}/executions") private @ResponseBody String getExecutions(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Integer id)` you could call `return getExecutions(request, response, id)`

Comment: I just wonder why it has to be private? Cause I will have to access to it through some other scenario... not only with this redirect .

Comment: It doesn't have to be private, it can be public and you can still call `return` on it.  If you do make it private, you can have multiple public methods that all return it.  It just depends on what different business logic needs to be performed with each method.

Comment: Ok thanks... I'll try that in the morning ... meanwhile I stumbled upon this... and it seems like a nice approach. [RedirectAttributes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html) @Shaggy125

Comment: Nice.  I've not seen that before.